# Azure pipeline rnuget restore aftefacts from another pipeline

Tags: azure-pipelines

I've got an Azure pipeline that makes a NuGet package and puts it into the pink *Artefacts* NuGet feed and I can use that from VisualStudio to install my package into another project.

However, the Azure pipeline for the consuming project cannot restore the nuget package. I think this is bcause of some security nonsense.

How can I get the Azure pipeline to restore the package?

This is the task

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet restore'
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    vstsFeed: 'Some-DLLs'
```

and this is the error

```
Build FAILED.

       "C:\agent\_work\19\s\neon-identity-samples.sln" (Restore target) (1) ->
       (Restore target) -> 
         C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.104\NuGet.targets(131,5): error : Unable to load the service index for source https://tfs.engineering.company.net/tfs/Software-Collection/_packaging/Some-DLLs/nuget/v3/index.json. [C:\agent\_work\19\s\samples.sln]
       C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.104\NuGet.targets(131,5): error :   No credentials are available in the security package [C:\agent\_work\19\s\samples.sln]

    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created a PAT and put it into the `nuget.config`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <clear />
    <add key="Some-DLLs" value="https://tfs.engineering.intelligentgaming.net/tfs/neon-collection/_packaging/Some-DLLs/nuget/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
  <packageSourceCredetials>
    <Some-DLLs>
      <add key="username" value="DEV\richard.barraclough" />
      <add key="password" value="bhyc4751jhozv7akw5rgpoy872ddminwzfio3npkhjbsrg88kfez" /> <!-- A PAT -->
    </Some-DLLs>
  </packageSourceCredetials>
</configuration>
```

(I don't care about security when it prevents things from working.)

Comment: However, I copied this to another repository in which it doesn't work. Thus YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

It seems this is a known issue [(1)](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/10399) [(2)](https://bartwullems.blogspot.com/2020/05/azure-pipelinesdotnet-restore-error.html), a user managed to get rid of this error by using 'custom' command instead of 'restore'. I could not reproduce your issue from my side, but the solution would be as follows:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet restore'
  inputs:
    command: 'custom'
    custom: 'restore'
    arguments: '--force'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    vstsFeed: 'Some-DLLs'
```

This error might also be caused by lack of authorization in the repository, in other words, it seems your nuget.config file doesn't have the credentials to access one the repositories, thus dotnet restore fails, therefore you'd need to make sure the credentials are correctly set in the nuget.config file of your project.